Is there a term for a number system where the digits can have any value you want?
Before, I had the idea of a number system where the digits can have any value you want, for example:
$$11 \langle10^{24}\rangle = 1\cdot100 + 1\cdot10 + 10^{24} = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,110 $$
Basically, it is normal decimal but digit values can exceed ten, and can also take negative and non-integer values. You can even have $\langle\pi\rangle5 = 36.4159…$ and $\langle e \rangle \langle e \rangle \langle e \rangle = 301.7292…$ Is there a term for these number systems?

Why give  something a nome without knowing any use for it?

I don't know a name for this but it's a very useful concept. Not new, but good for you for inventing it. Eleventy one (Bilbo Baggins's age at his famous birthday party) is a very nice number.
You are essentially writing polynomials in $x$ and then evaluating them at $x=10$ without further processing the coefficients to get to small digits in each place.
That way you can understand addition and multiplication without having to worry about what goes in which column in the "standard algorithms". When you're ready you can convert to the traditional convention where the digits must be between $0$ and $9$.
Read about exploding dots.

It's called a non-standard positional numeral system.

I don't think the definition and examples in that wikipedia article cover the OPs case, where the "digits" can be arbitrary integers.
